# Trouble quering a join in oracle sql

Tags: oracle, join

Theres a question on an exercise which asks me to write an SQL statement to show the SKU, SKU_Description, WarehouseID for all items stored in a warehouse managed by ‘Lucille Smith’. I have to use a join, but not use the JOIN ON syntax.

I came up with:

```
   select sku, sku_description, warehouseid 
   from inventory join warehouse
   inventory.warehouseid = warehouse.warehouseid
   where manager = 'lucille smith';
```

with the following errors

```
select Sku,SKU_DESCRIPTION,WAREHOUSEID 
from inventory join warehouse on
inventory.WAREHOUSEID = warehouse.warehouseid
          where manager = 'lucille smith'

Error starting at line : 3 in command -
select Sku,SKU_DESCRIPTION,WAREHOUSEID 
from inventory join warehouse on
inventory.WAREHOUSEID = warehouse.warehouseid
          where manager = 'lucille smith'
Error at Command Line : 3 Column : 28
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: Put up a test case on SQL Fiddle - and you could look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856016/can-you-have-an-inner-join-without-the-on-keyword).

Comment: _"column ambiguously defined"_ -- when you say `select ... warehouseid ...`, the `warehouseid` column of which table do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a couple of assumptions here but one of these should work or be close:

```
select inventory.Sku,inventory.SKU_DESCRIPTION,WAREHOUSEID 
from inventory join warehouse using (warehoueid) 
where manager = 'lucille smith'
```

Or

```
Select inventory.sku, inventory.sku_description, inventory.warehouseid
from inventory, warehouse 
where inventory.warehouseid = warehouse.warehouseid
and warehouse.manager='lucille smith'
```

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "but not use the JOIN ON syntax" may mean you should use the [older 8i style of joins](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6585774577187) that doesn't use words "JOIN ON" at all, or it may mean you should use ["JOIN USING"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17209/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55311) rather than "JOIN ON".  Hopefully they meant the latter.

Answer (score 0):

"ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined" means that both tables contain one or more of the columns in your select and/or predicate, and Oracle doesn't know from which table to pull/query the column.

Try putting an alias in front of each table, then putting the same alias in front of each column name.

(sorry I couldn't be more specific, without a describe of either table I'm not certain which column exists in both)